# A function $g(x)$ has one and only one real root if $g'(x)\leq k <0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives, roots, rolles-theorem

$g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then   $g(x)$ has one and only one real root if $g'(x)\leq k <0$.

Proof attempt:

Let us assume the contrary, i.e. $g(x)$ has no real zero at all.

Therefore, being continuous, $g(x)$ cannot be both positive and negative on $\mathbb{R}$ . So, firstly we assume that $g(x) <0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

We take some $a>0$. (WLOG, take $a=1$). Now, $g(1)/1<0$ and $g(1)/k >0$. So, $\displaystyle\frac{g(-g(1)/k)-g(1)}{-g(1)/k-1} \leq k <0 \implies -k \leq \displaystyle\frac{g(-g(1)/k)-g(1)}{g(1)/k+1} \implies 0<-k \leq g(-g(1)/k) $

So, we have found at least one  point in the domain, where $g(x)$ is positive. So, $g(x)$ must have a zero. Now, $g'(x)<0, \ \  \forall x \ \in \mathbb{R}$ makes the function one-to-one.

[Note that the numerator must be positive, since $1>- g(1)/k \implies g(-g(1)/k)>g(1)$]

For the assumption that $g(x)>0$, we consider the points $a<0$ and $-g(a)/k$ (WLOG, take $a=-1$). Everything else is kept the same.

Are the statement and the proof both correct, or is there any mistake?

Please verify.

Comment: Hint: you did not cover the cases of multiple zeros.

Comment: @maxmilgram I agree that it should be stated, but it is trivial since the function is strictly decreasing.

Comment: either only one zero exists, or none. that can be concluded directly from the nature of the derivative

Comment: I'm not so sure about "concluded directly from the nature of the derivative", considering that "nature of" isn't a mathematical notion. I think you'll want to invoke either Rolle's theorem or the fact that a function whose derivative is (strictly) negative on an interval is (strictly) decreasing there (as @tia suggested).

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes. I didn't not write it up .

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = \infty \quad (1)$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = -\infty \quad (2)$$

Lets prove the second statement, the first statement can be proved using a similar argument.

Let's assume the opposite, that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = C \neq -\infty$$

Now if we consider the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} g'(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{C-C}{h}$$
$$=0$$

Which contradicts the fact that $g'(x) < 0$ for all $x$. 
Since $g'(x) < 0$, $g(x)$ can't go to $+\infty$ as $x \to \infty$, so it goes to $-\infty$.

This proves that $g$ has only one real root.

Comment: Would you care to comment on my comment above, as the OP did not care!

Comment: For the example of $g(x) = (x-1)(x-2)$, $g'(x) = 2x - 3$, which is not strictly positive or negative for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. An example for $g(x)$ would be $-x$ with $g'(x) = -1, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you much!